# Backbone model method not incrementing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to grok Backbone a little more, and from someone who has only used Backbone views in the past, I'm now trying my hand with Models and Collections.

Right now, when I post a comment, I try to increment the comment count.

Model:

```
Comment = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        text: null,
        count: 0
    },

    updateCount : function() {
        console.log(this.set('count', this.get('count') + 1));
        console.log(this.get('count'));
    }
});
```

Collection:

```
CommentsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Comment,
    initialize: function (models, options) {
        this.on("add", options.view.appendComment);
        this.on('add', options.view.resetComment);
    }
});
```

View:

```
CommentsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("body"),
        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this,
                    'addComment',
                    'appendComment',
                    'resetComment'
                    );
            this.comments = new CommentsCollection(null, {
                model: Comment,
                view: this
            });
        },
        events: {
            "click #post-comment": "addComment"
        },

        addComment: function (evt) {
            var $target = $(evt.currentTarget);
            var $container = $target.closest('#comment-wrapper');
            var text = $container.find('textarea').val();

            var comment = new Comment({
                text: text
            });

            //Add a new comment model to our comment collection
            this.comments.add(comment);

            return this;
        },

        appendComment: function (model) {
            $('#comments').prepend('<div> ' + model.get('text') + '</div>');
            model.updateCount();

            return this;
        },

        resetComment: function () {
            $('textarea').val('');
        }
    });
```

Why is it always returning 1 (add a comment and click Post then view the console to see)?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZkBWZ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're storing the count on the `Comment` model. Each time you hit the submit button, you create a new `Comment` which has the `count` set to the default, `0`. The method `updateCount` then updates the count on that brand new model, so you're always seeing 1.

If you're just looking to determine how many comments have been made, I'd suggest you just look at the size of the `CommentsCollection`. In `appendComment`, you can do it this way:

```
    appendComment: function (model) {
        $('#comments').prepend('<div> ' + model.get('text') + '</div>');
        // Get the number of comments
        console.log(model.collection.models.length);

        return this;
    },
```